# which pdf library supports SVG tag in ZF2

Tags: svg, zend-framework2, pdf-generation

I have tried using 3 PDF libraries(ZendPdf, DomPDF and wkhtmltopdf) in Zend Framework 2 to generate PDF Reports. All of them can generate basic HTML to PDF but do not seem to support SVG tags. Text and styles are rendered but SVG element comes blank in PDF.

I am trying to generate PDF Report files for charts generated by ExtJs which uses SVG tags. I am able to render simple html tags like(P with css styles) but unable to render SVG tags. It comes blank for svg. It is unable to render svg tags but other text and html can be read and rendered.

Please suggest if there is any tweak or the libraries do not support SVG tags. If you need I can provide you Sample HTML to experiment.

Hence, the question remains the same:

> Blockquote

Which pdf library supports SVG tag in ZF2 (Zend Framework 2) and how to do that(if possible, please provide example code)?

> Blockquote

Comment: I don't know much about ZF2 but did you look at TCPDF? http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_058.phps

Comment: can you post the html code you are trying to convert into pdf

Answer (score 0):

[PHP wrapper for PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com/php.htm) should do the trick. [Here](http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/svg_to_pdf_conversion.htm) is a list of supported SVG tags.

Comment: Hi, It seems PD4ML does not support ZF2. Please let me know that library which can be used through ZF2 also.

Comment: The following tutorial explains how to use PD4ML with Zend Framework 2: http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/pd4ml_and_zend_framework_2.htm